# MySQL - select an entry with the most entrys in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

the order is:
Display the user with the most items for sale listed by item and sale price.

Unfortunately, I don't quite know how to do that. My current state is:

```
SELECT item_id, item_name, item_price, user_id
FROM user
JOIN item ON user_id = user_id_seller
ORDER BY count(user_id_seller) desc
```

I have a table that contains items with a sales price. Each item is sold by some user. Now I just want to show the user who sells the most items, but show by item and price.

Comment: COUNT without GROUP BY? this makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

> Display the user with the most items for sale listed by item and sale price.

You can determine the user (or a user if there are ties) with the most items using an aggregation query and then ordering by the number of items and limiting to one row.

Then, just join back to `items`:

```
select i.*
from items i join
     (select i2.user_id_seller
      from items i2
      group by i2.user_id_seller
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1
     ) i2
     using (user_id_seller);
```

If you need additional user information (which the question is not clear on), you can join in `users` as well.

Comment: Hmm, there seems to be an error in the query. I can't execute it, as there is an error in the syntax. Can you take another look at it? And to answer your additional questions, everything is fine. I just need the items an seller_id.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT item_id, item_name, item_price, user_id 
FROM user 
JOIN (select user_seller_id,count(item.id) as item_count 
      GROUP BY user_id_seller) as items
     on user_id = items.user_id_seller 
ORDER BY item_count desc
```